# jQuery Create New LI tag in existing Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create new **`<li>`** element and it should add that item to existing bootstrap dropdown menu **`(<ul>)`** by automatically using jQuery. The newly created item should also be auto-selected in dropdown.

Can somebody please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Items <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu reddy" role="menu">
      <li><input type="text" class="form-control"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Create New</button></li>
      <li><a href="#"><label for="menuitem1"><input type="checkbox" id="menuitem1" /> Menu Item 1</label></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><label for="menuitem2"><input type="checkbox" id="menuitem2" /> Menu Item 2</label></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><label for="menuitem3"><input type="checkbox" id="menuitem3" /> Menu Item 3</label></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-control{max-width:140px;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-left:10px;}
.btn{margin-top:5px;}
.open>.dropdown-menu{width:250px;}
```

Please find the Preview in "[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/s9Lkdpev/5/)" here

Comment: It is good practice to formally accept an answer which adequately resolves your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add HTML using the `append()` method. To "auto" select a new checkbox in your new menu item, just set the `checked` attribute to "checked"

```
 $("#createnew").on("click", function() {    
    var $dropdown = $(".dropdown-menu.reddy");
    var menuItemNo = $dropdown.find("li").length;
    var menuItemId = "menuitem" + menuItemNo;    

    $dropdown.append("<li><a href='#'><label for='" + menuItemId + "'><input type='checkbox' id='" + menuItemId + "' checked='checked' /> Menu Item " + menuItemNo +"</label></a></li>");
});
```

See an updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/br98nxj9/1/

Comment: Really sorry @Chris, But I need to show Newly created value ("from textfield") not the pretext with Menu Item... I am not expert in jQuery if you can help me I will be more happy... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Prasad - You can do that by extracting the value from the textbox's jQuery object, using `val()`. I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/br98nxj9/2/

Comment: this is getting even better now :)... To extend, How can I add a validation that, if input is empty, then menu item should not be created, just add .error class to the textfield. Once menu item is created, input value should be blurred out automatically and also duplicate values should not be allowed... I know I am asking too much, but that is the requirement. Can you please?

Comment: You can use jQuery Validate (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to accomplish this. I've updated the fiddle here to show a _rough_ example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/br98nxj9/3/ - there's some wrapping issues, but it shows how to use the validate script in its simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated this a 'little'. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pamxnouh/

This is the javascript that is used. Make sure to give your create button a 'new-li' id.

```
$('#new-li').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var x = $(event.target).closest('ul').find("a").size()+1;
    $(event.target).closest('ul').append("<li><a href='#'><label for='menuitem"+x+"'><input type='checkbox' id='menuitem"+x+"' />"+$(event.target).siblings('input').first().val()+"</label></a></li>");
    $(event.target).closest('ul').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    $(event.target).closest('ul').find('input').last().prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Hi Nils... Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry to say, this code is not working. As I am very newbie to the code, I am not able to find where the exact problem is..

Please check [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/s9Lkdpev/1/)

Comment: Hi Nils,

Thanks for quick reply again

This is working like a champ... I have checked it twice :)

Keep up the Greate work!

Comment: Just updated this according to your fiddle that I missed earlier.